# Subsetting Dask DataFrames

Tags: python, dask

Is this a valid way of loading subsets of a dask dataframe to memory:

```
while i < len_df:
    j = i + batch_size 
    if j > len_df: 
        j = len_df
    subset = df.loc[i:j,'source_country_codes'].compute()
```

I read somewhere that this may not be correct because of how dask assigns index numbers because of it dividing the bigger dataframe into smaller pandas dfs. Also I don't think dask dataframes has an `iloc` attribute.
I am using version 0.15.2

In terms of use cases, this would be a way of loading batches of data to deep learning (say keras).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dataset has well known divisions then this might work, but instead I recommend just computing one partition at a time.

```
for part in df.to_delayed():
    subset = part.compute()
```

You can roughly control the size by repartitioning beforehand

```
for part in df.repartition(npartitions=100).to_delayed():
    subset = part.compute()
```

This isn't exactly the same, because it doesn't guarantee a fixed number of rows in each partition, but that guarantee might be quite expensive, depending on how the data is obtained.

Comment: But the latter method will guarantee that I will run through the entire dataset right? I should also mention that I had done this earlier: `df = dd.from_pandas(df, 16)`. Will it cause a clash or just do another partition?

Comment: Yes, this will include the entire dataset.  You can repartition safely.  Or you can call from_pandas with a different number of partitions.  Everything should work fine here either way.