# Shuffling data in dask

Tags: python, dask

This is a follow on question from [Subsetting Dask DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820223/subsetting-dask-dataframes). I wish to shuffle data from a **dask dataframe** before sending it in batches to a ML algorithm.

The answer in that question was to do the following:

```
for part in df.repartition(npartitions=100).to_delayed():
    batch = part.compute()
```

However, even if I was to shuffle the contents of batch I'm a bit worried that it might not be ideal. The data is a time series set so datapoints would be highly correlated within each partition.

What I would ideally like is something along the lines of:

```
rand_idx = np.random.choice(len(df), batch_size, replace=False)
batch = df.iloc[rand_idx, :]
```

which would work on pandas but not dask. Any thoughts?

### Edit 1: Potential Solution

I tried doing

```
train_len = int(len_df*0.8)
idx = np.random.permutation(len_df)
train_idx = idx[:train_len]
test_idx = idx[train_len:]
train_df = df.loc[train_idx]
test_df = df.loc[test_idx]
```

However, if I try doing `train_df.loc[:5,:].compute()` this return a 124451 row dataframe. So clearly using dask wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend adding a column of random data to your dataframe and then using that to set the index:

```
df = df.map_partitions(add_random_column_to_pandas_dataframe, ...)
df = df.set_index('name-of-random-column')
```

Comment: Could I not have simply done `df['rand_index'] = np.random.permutation(len(df))` for the first line?

Comment: Seems like this behaviour should be built in. So we can automatically add a random column  that isn't used and then shuffle the entire dataframe. Shuffling each individual partition is not enough, one must shuffle across the entire dataframe.

Comment: Related about this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923274/appending-new-column-to-dask-dataframe?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue recently and came up with a different approach using dask array and shuffle_slice introduced in this [pull request](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/3901)

It shuffles the whole sample

```
import numpy as np
from dask.array.slicing import shuffle_slice

d_arr = df.to_dask_array(True)
df_len = len(df)
np.random.seed(42)
index = np.random.choice(df_len, df_len, replace=False)
d_arr = shuffle_slice(d_arr, index)
```

and to transform back to dask dataframe

```
df = d_arr.to_dask_dataframe(df.columns)
```

for me it works well for large data sets

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to separate your dataframe into training and testing subsets, it is what does [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)  and it works with `pandas.DataFrame`. (Go [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24151789/6914989) for an example)

And for your case of using it with `dask`, you may be interested by the library `dklearn`, that seems to implements this function.

> To do that, we can use the train_test_split function, which mirrors
>   the scikit-learn function of the same name. We'll hold back 20% of the
>   rows:
>
> ```
> from dklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
>
> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.2)
> ```

More information [here](https://jcrist.github.io/dask-sklearn-part-3.html).

**Note:** I did not perform any test with `dklearn`, this is just a thing I came across, but I hope it can help.

---

**EDIT:** what about [`dask.DataFrame.random_split`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.random_split)?

> Examples
>
> 50/50 split
>
> ```
> >>> a, b = df.random_split([0.5, 0.5])
> ```
>
> 80/10/10 split, consistent random_state
>
> ```
> >>> a, b, c = df.random_split([0.8, 0.1, 0.1], random_state=123)
> ```

Use for ML applications is illustrated [here](https://github.com/dask/dask-ml/blob/4de3f819823d8850ae6956b1465de7086bedf7c4/docs/source/xgboost.rst)

Comment: Hi Fabien, I'm afraid dklearn doesn't exist anymore. I actually saw that blogpost but couldn't get much out of it for that reason.

Comment: @Sachin_ruk , I think I found another solution (builtin from `dask.DataFrame`), see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

For people here really just wanting to shuffle the rows as the title implies:

**This is costly**

```
import numpy as np
random_idx = np.random.permutation(len(sd.index))
sd.assign(random_idx=random_idx)
sd = sd.set_index('x', sorted=True)
```