# Appending new column to dask dataframe

Tags: python, dask

This is a follow up question to [Shuffling data in dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842155/shuffling-data-in-dask/46848375#46848375).

I have an existing dask dataframe `df` where I wish to do the following:

```
df['rand_index'] = np.random.permutation(len(df))
```

However, this gives the error, `Column assignment doesn't support type ndarray`. I tried to use `df.assign(rand_index = np.random.permutation(len(df))` which gives the same error.

Here is a minimal (not) working sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

df = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3]*10, 'B':[3,2,1]*10}), npartitions=10)
df['rand_index'] = np.random.permutation(len(df))
```

### Note:

The previous question mentioned using `df = df.map_partitions(add_random_column_to_pandas_dataframe, ...)` but I'm not sure if that is relevant to this particular case.

### Edit 1

I attempted
`df['rand_index'] = dd.from_array(np.random.permutation(len_df))` which, executed without an issue. When I inspected `df.head()` it seems that the new column was created just fine. However, when I look at `df.tail()` the `rand_index` is a bunch of `NaN`s.

In fact just to confirm I checked `df.rand_index.max().compute()` which turned out to be smaller than `len(df)-1`. So this is probably where `df.map_partitions` comes into play as I suspect this is an issue with dask being partitioned. In my particular case I have 80 partitions (not referring to the sample case).

Answer (score 9):

You would need to turn `np.random.permutation(len(df))` into type that dask understands:

```
permutations = dd.from_array(np.random.permutation(len(df)))
df['rand_index'] = permutations
df
```

This would yield:

```
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                    A      B rand_index
npartitions=10                         
0               int64  int64      int32
3                 ...    ...        ...
...               ...    ...        ...
27                ...    ...        ...
29                ...    ...        ...
Dask Name: assign, 61 tasks
```

So it is up to you now if you want to `.compute()` to calculate actual results.

Comment: This is a problem if the indices are not the same (e.g. the original df has a datetime index and the new `Series` has a int index)

Answer (score 0):

To assign a column you should use [df.assign](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.assign)

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work. Doing `df = df.assign(rand_index2=dd.from_array(np.random.permutation(len_df)))` still gave me `NaN`s in `df.tail()`

Comment: Which dask version are you using?
`df = df.assign(rand_index=dd.from_array(np.random.permutation(len(df))))`
works for me.

Comment: version `0.15.3`

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem as in Edit 1.

My work around is to get a unique column from the existing dataframe and feed into the dataframe that is to be appended.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
import panda as pd

df = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3]*2, 'B':[3,2,1]*2, 'idx':[0,1,2,3,4,5]}), npartitions=10)
chunks = tuple(df.map_partitions(len).compute())
size = sum(chunks)
permutations = da.from_array(np.random.permutation(len(df)), chunks=chunks)
idx = da.from_array(df['idx'].compute(), chunks=chunks)
ddf = dd.concat([dd.from_dask_array(c) for c in [idx,permutations]], axis = 1)
ddf.columns = ['idx','rand_idx']
df = df.merge(ddf, on='idx')
df = df.set_index('rand_idx')
df.compute().head()
```